# A simpler way to calculate this easy probability?

Tags: probability

I did the following simple exercise:
[image]

I tried $\frac{P(N\geq1 \wedge N \leq 4)}{P(N\leq 4)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2*3}+\frac{1}{3*4}+\frac{1}{4*5}+\frac{1}{5*6}}{\frac{1}{1*2}+\frac{1}{2*3}+\frac{1}{3*4}+\frac{1}{4*5}+\frac{1}{5*6}}=...=\frac{28800}{57600}$ by using a calclulator.

I found punching numbers into a calculator very tedious and repetitive. I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do it?

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$\mathbb P\{N\geq 1\mid N\leq 4\}=1-\mathbb P\{N=0\mid N\leq 4\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Those series telescope, that is, you can write: $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, telescoping. If $f(n) = 1/((n+1)(n+2))$, then

$\sum_{n=0}^N f(n) = \frac{N+1}{N+2}$.